# How to send JsonObject Post request with image using Retrofit (Java)

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I want to send a post request which contains jsonObject and an image and various other fields and I used MultiPart for image and have successfully uploaded the image but the jsonObject is uploaded in string format

Here is my Api Interface

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("operator/upload")
    Call<JsonObject>upload(@Header ("Authorization") String t,
                           @Part MultipartBody.Part img,
                           @Part("fullName") RequestBody name,
                           @Part("fatherName") RequestBody fathername,
                           @Part("aadharNumber") RequestBody aadharnumber,
                           @Part("dob") RequestBody dob,
                           @Part("registeredAddress") RequestBody address,
                           @Part("gender") RequestBody gender,
                           @Part("plantId") RequestBody plant,
                           @Part MultipartBody.Part data,
                           @Part("authorized") Boolean auth,
                           @Part("verified") Boolean ver) ;
```

Here is the Retrofit service function

```
public void userUpload(String p, MultipartBody.Part image, RequestBody name, RequestBody fathername, RequestBody aadharnumber, RequestBody dob, RequestBody address, RequestBody gender, RequestBody plant, MultipartBody.Part cap, Boolean aut, Boolean ver, Response_listner response_listner) {

        Call<JsonObject> call = api_interface.upload(p, image, name, fathername, aadharnumber, dob, address, gender, plant,cap,aut,ver);
        serveCall(call, response_listner);

    }
```

The ServeCall Method is here

```
private void serveCall(Call<JsonObject> call, Response_listner responce_listner) {

        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {

                try {
                    responce_listner.onResponseSuccess(response);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {

                try {
                    responce_listner.onResponseFailure(t);
                    Log.d("Network", t.getMessage());
                    Log.d("Network Cause", t.getCause().getMessage());
                    Log.d("NetworkStack", t.getStackTrace().toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And My Main Code where I Made an Api Call

```
 HashMap<String, String> num2 = new HashMap<>();
                num2.put("client_id",String.valueOf(CLIENT_ID));
                num2.put("full_name",String.valueOf(FULL_NAME));
                num2.put("aadhaar_number",String.valueOf(AADHAR_NUMBER));
                num2.put("dob",String.valueOf(DOB));
                num2.put("gender",String.valueOf(GENDER));
                num2.put("face_status",String.valueOf(FACE_STATUS));
                num2.put("face_score",String.valueOf(FACE_SCORE));
                num2.put("zip",String.valueOf(ZIP));
                num2.put("profile_image",String.valueOf(PROFILE_IMAGE));
                num2.put("has_image",String.valueOf(HAS_IMAGE));
                num2.put("mobile_hash",String.valueOf(MOBILE_HASH));
                num2.put("raw_xml",String.valueOf(RAW_XML));
                num2.put("zip_data",String.valueOf(ZIP_DATA));
                num2.put("care_of",String.valueOf(CARE_OF));
                num2.put("share_code",String.valueOf(SHARE_CODE));
                num2.put("mobile_verified",String.valueOf(MOBILE_VERIFIED));
                num2.put("reference_id",String.valueOf(REFERENCE_ID));

MultipartBody.Part delta = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("aadharDetails", num2.toString());

RetrofitClient.getInstance_new().userUpload(TokenData, image, name, fathername, aadharnumber, dobb, addresss, genderr, plant,delta, auth, ver, new Response_listner() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponseSuccess(Response baseResponse) throws IOException, JSONException {
                                        if (baseResponse.isSuccessful()) {

                                            Log.e("Response",baseResponse.body().toString());

                                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(baseResponse.body().toString());

   

                                                prog_close();
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterOP.this, Done.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                finish();
                                            }

//                                        }
                                        } else {
                                         
                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterOP.this, baseResponse.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }


                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponseFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                                        
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterOP.this, throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                    }
                                });
```

So the data that I'm sending all is good except **delta** which is request body somehow it sends string rather than HashMap

Your Help Is Greatly Appreciated !!

Comment: CHECK THIS ANSWER IF IT CAN HELP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58079454/6534707

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel Thanks For Your Response, But I don't need to send Array but Just Pure Json Object if you have any suggestion please say !!

Comment: you need to ignore array, check for how it sends image.

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel I Don't have any error for sending Images, my main issue is to send the JsonObject which goes into database as String and not object !!

Comment: refer this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21423093/6534707